# Custom Post type in Author.php

Tags: custom-post-types

Please i have been battling this issue for days now... I want to display custom post types in author archive and was able to get this code to display them earlier today:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_author() ) {

        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'design', 'accessory');


    }

});
```

The post types in the field above is my custom post types. The problem now is it only displays one of the post types(design). Please any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the post types as an array, not each as its own argument.

```
$q->set( 'post_type', ['design', 'accessory']);
//                    ^                     ^
```

Or if you're on older PHP systems

```
$q->set( 'post_type', array('design', 'accessory'));
```